# How can I predefine a search value in serverside processing datatables?

Tags: datatables, server-side-rendering

When my page is loaded, I would like that my search field is filled with the word "elephant" and the data is already filtered by the search value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        search: "elephants",
        ajax: {
             url: "/getdata",
             dataSrc: 'data'
        },
    });
});
```

What is the best way to do this with server side processing datatables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this for server-side processing the same way you do this for client-side processing.

Instead of this:

```js
search: "elephants",
```

Use this:

```js
search: {
  search: "elephants"
},
```

This will do 2 things: (1) It will display `elephants` in the global search box. (2) It will cause this search term to be submitted to the server as part of the server-side request, the very first time the table is displayed.

The relevant section of your server-side request:

```js
"search": {
    "value": "elephants",
    "regex": false
}
```

You will see that DataTables has added the default value of `"regex": false` to the request, also.

Of course, it is up to your server-side code to process this request data, extract the global search term, and apply it as a filter, before returning any data to the browser.

---

To see the full set of values which can be used with the `search` option, see the documentation for [`search`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search).

One of these sub-values is `search` - that is why you also have a documentation page for [`search.search`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.search).

The other [options](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search) you can use are:

- `caseInsensitive`
- `regex`
- `smart`